# Checking if Post Correspondence Problem has a Solution

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata

I have the following problem

[image]

I think that solution is wrong because x1=b and y1=b3(cube).They do not match,So how is this solution possible?

Comment: Look at what the two sides spell out. LHS: $babbb | b | b | ba = babbbbbba=bab^6a$. RHS: $ba | bbb | bbb | a=babbbbbba=bab^6a$. Sure seems like a legit solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

### Post Correspondence Problem (PCP) :

Given a PCP instance P, a match is a nonempty sequence
$$i_1, i_2, . . . , i_l$$
of numbers from $\{1, 2, . . . , k\}$ (with repetition) such that

$$t_{i1}. t_{i2}· · · t_i = b_{i1} .b_{i2}· · · b_i$$

### Modified PCP (MPCP):

$MPCP = \{< P > | P$ is a PCP instance and it has a match which starts with
index $1\}$.

---

Given solution is correct, since you are thinking about MPCP and question asking is about PCP.